# The jsfiddle cursor's apparent position is not it's actual position in Chrome and IE. Works in Firefox

Tags: editor, jsfiddle, cursor-position

Noticing today that on long lines of code or comments, the cursor progressively gets more and more incorrectly positioned until its apparent position can be off by more than 3 characters. (This looks like the editor thinks it is working with a different font.)

I see this in Chrome and IE. However Firefox is working fine.  Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. Using the latest version of chrome (currently 39.0.2171.65)

Comment: yep, same for me... I'm just using a lot more Plunker now.

Answer (score 13):

Hope they fix it. Turn off text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; in the body element and you should be good for the meantime.

In Chrome you do it this way:

- Open the fiddle you want to edit
- Open the chrome-console (f12)
- select "elements" tab
- select the "body" tag
- scroll the "styles" area (on the right side) down to the "normalize.css"
- finally uncheck the checkbox next to "text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;"

Now the cursor is fixed until you reload the page.

Comment: If you are using [Styish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), then you can use this style: https://userstyles.org/styles/107637/jsfiddle-caret-fix-for-chrome

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [user1803096](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27097832/1414562) for the quick fix. Now because it is boring to each time use the inspector to remove this specific CSS rule, i prefer to copy/paste and execute in console following javascript:

```
var css = '*, body, button, input, textarea, select {text-rendering: initial;}',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
```

Hope this will be fixed soon.

Comment: Fantastic thanks, this has been killing me for a few weeks - tampermonkey script is up and running!